# What is the difference between "не надо" and "не нужно"?

Tags: выбор-слова, разница

Is there any difference between **не надо** and **не нужно**? If there is, what is it?

For example: 
A pizza delivery guy comes to my home and brings pizza. Its cost is 650 руб and I give him 700 руб. Now he wants to give me the change and I want to tell him that there is no need for that. What would you choose? (**не надо** / **не нужно**)

Answer (score 5):

`Нужно` is slightly less casual and more bookish, so, while phrases "Ой, Вась, может не нужно тут нам голову-то морочить" is completely OK but native speaker most probably will use `на надо`.

On the other hand, professor most likely will not say during a lecture 'В творчестве этого поэта надо различать три этапа' but rather `нужно`.

There's also `необходимо` which is even more (sort of) high-style than `нужно` but understandably not used with "не" - double negation is just not a typical for Russian (so, you can use "необходимо" instead of "нужно", but not "не необходимо" instead of "не нужно").

Also, it looks like that `надо` is slowly but steadily overpowering "нужно" even in official usage.

So, answering specifically the last part of your question, I'd go with "Спасибо большое, сдачи не надо".

Answer (score 1):

Historically, ***надо*** is similar to а past participle form (cf. *English -de*, Spanish *-d@* and Swedish *-d(e) / -t*).

***Нужно***, in turn, represents a cluster of historically ***-нъ***-ending words which in modern Russian are at a borderline between an adjective and a participle (cf. English *driven*, *striken*, etc).

Both forms are related to Proto-Germanic [naudiz](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/naudiz).

In my opinion, both forms are also related to German *nehmen* and Dutch *niemen*.

The word stems are preserved in modern Russian interjections:

***на!*** = here you are! / Take it! (lit. 'you-take-it!', often with a less friendly / respective connotation) and

***ну!*** = give it (away)! I'm waiting / I agree / come on / yep, ok (lit. 'I-take-it' or 'let me take it'), used with a somewhat more friendly emphasis.

Hence, the overtones would be like

***не надо*** = It is not needed 'from your part / point of view / for/from you'

***не нужно*** = it is not needed from my part / point of view / for/from me'.

But most native speakers would not care about the difference, anyway, or would not explain it.

PS The proverbial etymology of ***надо*** as a form of ***надобно*** doesn't stand any etymological scrutiny not just because words starting with ***на-*** in general were  very unlucky when interpreted by Vasmer and Co, but also because such an etymology doesn't explain the sound alteration in ***надо*** and ***нужно***.

Also, stating that -до is not a suffix but a part of stem one has to admit the same for words like ***чудо, стадо*** and ***говядо.***